# Bus Bar voltage calculations for renewable integration to grid

Tags: voltage-divider, generator, voltage-measurement, busbar

I am confused on the problem bellow
[image: Question]

I started off by use P=IV = V^2/Z --> V=sqrt(P*Z)

Assume at each bus bar the power from the PV is being given to the grid with +6KW from knowning that the PV produces 10KW but the load PL uses 4KW

We know that z = 0.2

Thus, V = sqrt(6 *10^3 *0.2) = 34.64 V. This means that the voltage level at each bus bar is 230+34.64

Thus the voltage at each bus bar is 264?
This is because each bus bar outputs 6KW to grid i think.

Thus in P.U V = 264/230 = 1.15 ??

Wrong! :""( i am soo confused as to how to approach this problem.

The notes only say general stuff like if PL == Ppv then voltage == 1 p.u

Please help me understand this simple problem

Comment: You are just trying to combine numbers without thinking. \$P=IV = V^2/Z\$ is  a formula for power dissipation in a resistor at certain voltage across it. Neither \$P_L\$ nor \$P_{PV}\$ dissipates in the 0.2 Ohm resistor. Doesn't your textbook describe a methodology for solving such problems?

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve this is the same as I did but make sure that the power is the sum of all the powers at bus 1
Also assume 230v at all but bars

This gives you, the current I1 at bus 1
I.e. P=18Kw thus current at bus 1 I1=18000/230 =78.3A thus v2 = 78.3 *.2=15.7v
This is the voltage rise due to the PV at bus 1
Thus V1 = 230+16= 246

For Bus 2, P= 12Kw this I= 12000/230 =52A
V2 =52*0.2=10.4=10 (approx) thus 246 +10
V2 = 256v

Bus 3, P=6kw thus I =6000/230 =26A
V3= 26*0.2 =5.2v thus 256+5.2=261v